# How To Probabilistically Line up Names and Birthdays

Tags: database, probability, medical

I am working with different datasets that involve the same people. However, since neither data set has any concept of a distinct person YET (despite being generated by the same organization) lining up people from these two data sets is not awesome.

Currently, we are using a 1990's Center for Disease Control and Prevention tool called [LinkedPlus](http://www.cdc.gov/cancer/npcr/tools/registryplus/lp.htm). This piece of software seems pretty cool - it will find a phonetic representation of the name field in two different datasets, and depending on the phonetic difference (how different the names sound) it will join the records with a certainty factor.

All of the dataset generation up to this point has been automated (they used to do it manually, by hand, before I got involved!) However, I don't see any kind of LinkedPlus APIs, or any way to automate this. Basically, I'd like some kind of a [phonetic analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phonetic-matching.html) [api](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-phonetic/index.html) and then a difference between birthdays (but probabilistic based on human keying errors, so the same day/month/year but with one digit difference would be 'close' or with a transpose error would also be close.)

Do you guys know if there anything like this, especially for medical data, other than this ancient CDC tool? Honestly, if this tool had an API it would probably be perfect.

I can always write a windows script to click on positions on the screen to automate LinkedPlus...

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: I could implement an soundex comparison algorithm, but I think using an existing implementation would make more sense. Any well documented, existing, solution would have off-site resources, making it off-topic. How would you suggest I edit this question to make it on-topic?

Comment: As already mentioned, you can't ask here for a recommendation, period. It's either going to be to an off-site resource or it's going to become opinion based, neither of which are appropriate here. The one possibility I can see for your question is to take it to [softwarerecs.se] instead, which is the only technical site of which I'm aware here that allows this sort of question.